# How could I handle multiple list items being put into a temporary placeholder, and set back to the place where it was removed from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, html-lists

Description of my issue:

I have a html list which created on the fly from an XML, read by PHP. The XML consist a parent node as FRUITS, mid-level nodes as working days(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY), and leaves as fruits(APPLE, BANANA, PEAR...)

Leaves, the fruits (APPLE, BANANA, PEAR...) could be drag&dropped between the mid-level items (Workdays of the week) freely. 
I also added a feature that the leaf nodes(APPLE, BANANA, PEAR...) can be put back to the Pantry, so temporary being deleted from the leaf nodes. When it is placed int to the Pantry, the trash icon changes to recycle icon which can put back the leaf (APPLE, BANANA, PEAR...) under the mid-level node (Workdays of the week).

Movements are desired only on client side, no database or any file system storage needed.

I would like the code work, but I stucked in the Javascript. It works properly when the code handles the first mid-level item. When I tried to handle all the leaves(APPLE, BANANA, PEAR...) in other mid-levels(other working days after monday), the code doesn't work properly. The Javascript code based on some JQuery example, sortable, dragable, droppable codes.

So I would like to ask your help about how could I handle multiple list items being put into a temporary placeholder, and set back to the place where it was removed from?

Any help are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gaboo

Code samples

Javascript code comes as follows:

```
$(function() {
        $("#sortable,#sortable2,#sortable3,#sortable4,#sortable5,#droptarget").sortable({
            revert: false,
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            cursor: 'move',
            helper: "clone",
            handle: '.drag'
        }).disableSelection();
        $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "ul"
        }).hover( function (){
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        var $mcTree = $( "#sortable" ),$mcContainer = $( "#droptarget" );

        // let the pantry be droppable, accepting the fruit items
        $mcContainer.droppable({
            accept: "#sortable > li",
            activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                deleteImage( ui.draggable );
            }
        });
        // let the fruit be droppable as well, accepting items from the pantry
        $mcTree.droppable({
            accept: "#droptarget li",
            activeClass: "custom-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                recycleImage( ui.draggable );
            }
        });
        // image deletion function
        var recycle_icon = '<a href="" title="Recycle this image" class="remove ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">Delete Leaf</a>';
        function deleteImage($item) {
            $item.fadeOut(function() {
                var $list = $('ul',$mcContainer).length ? $('ul',$mcContainer) : $('<span "/>').appendTo($mcContainer);

                $item.find('a.ui-icon-trash').remove();
                $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
                    $item.animate({ width: '140px' }).find('img').animate({ height: '72px' }).css({'border-color':'red'});
                });
            });
        }
        // image recycle function
        var trash_icon = '<a href="" title="Delete this image" class="remove ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Recycle Leaf</a>';
        function recycleImage($item) {
            $item.fadeOut(function() {
                $item.find('a.ui-icon-refresh').remove();
                $item.css('width','140px').append(trash_icon).find('img').css({'height':'72px'}).end().appendTo($mcTree).fadeIn();
            });
        }
        // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
        $('ul#sortable > li').click(function(ev) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $target = $(ev.target);

            if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-trash')) {
                deleteImage($item);
            } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-zoomin')) {
                viewLargerImage($target);
            } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-refresh')) {
                recycleImage($item);
            }

            return false;
        });


    });
```

XML code looks like as follows:

```
<parent id="FRUITS">
<mid-level id="MONDAY">
    <leaf id="APPLE" />
    <leaf id="BANANA" />
</mid-level>
<mid-level id="TUESDAY">
    <leaf id="PEAR" />
    <leaf id="STRAWBERRY" />
    <leaf id="NUT" />
</mid-level>
<mid-level id="WEDNESDAY">
</mid-level>
<mid-level id="THURSDAY">
    <leaf id="BLACKBERRY" />
    <leaf id="PEANUT" />
    <leaf id="MANGO" />
    <leaf id="GRAPE" />
</mid-level>
<mid-level id="FRIDAY">
    <leaf id="ALMOND" />
</mid-level>
```

HTML code looks like as follows:

```
<div id='container'>
  <span class='left' id='mTree'>
    <ul>
      <li>FRUITS</li>
        <ul>
          <li>MONDAY</li>
            <ul id="sortable" class="mct connectedSortable droptrue">
              <li>
                <div id="leaf">
                  <span class='leafId'>APPLE</span>
                  <span class='info ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>
                  <span class='drag ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4'></span>
                  <span><a href='' title='Delete this image' class='remove ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete Leaf</a></span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div id="leaf">
                  <span class='leafId'>BANANA</span>
                  <span class='info ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>
                  <span class='drag ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4'></span>
                  <span><a href='' title='Delete this image' class='remove ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete Leaf</a></span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          <li>TUESDAY</li>
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable droptrue">
              <li>
                <div id="leaf">
                  <span class='leafId'>PEAR</span>
                  <span class='info ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>
                  <span class='drag ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4'></span>
                  <span><a href='' title='Delete this image' class='remove ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete Leaf</a></span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>STRAWBERRY</li>
              <li>NUT</li>
            </ul>
          <li>WEDNESDAY</li>
            <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable droptrue"></ul>
          <li>THURSDAY</li>
            <ul id="sortable4" class="connectedSortable droptrue">
              <li>BLACKBERRY</li>
              <li>PEANUT</li>
              <li>MANGO</li>
              <li>GRAPE</li>
            </ul>
          <li>FRIDAY</li>
            <ul id="sortable5" class="connectedSortable droptrue">
              <li>ALMOND</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </span>
    <span class='right' id='mContainer'>
       <span class='containerTitle ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span> 
       <span>Pantry</span>
         <div id='droptarget' class='connectedSortable droptrue'></div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <li>APPLE<br/></li>
  <li>BANANA<br/></li>
  <li>PEAR<br/></li>
  <li>STRAWBERRY<br/></li>
  <li>NUT<br/></li>
  <li>BLACKBERRY<br/></li>
  <li>PEANUT<br/></li>
  <li>MANGO<br/></li>
  <li>GRAPE<br/></li>
  <li>ALMOND<br/></li>
```

Comment: +1 For very well documented and worded first question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .data() function in jQuery to do what you are trying to do. To do that effectively, you are going to need to change your HTML slightly. You have multiple cases of 'id="leaf"' and you cannot do that. ID's are designed to be used once, and only once.

Perhaps you should make them id_1, id_2, id_3, etc. This would also help with what I am going to propose.

In your callback functions for the 'drop' event in droppable, you would want to capture the original ID that you are removing it from, and store it in a data attribute. For example:

```
var that = $(this);
that.data('source', that.parents('div')[0].attr('id'));
```

Then, when you are restoring everything, you would grab the original ID and just append the item back to where it belongs.

```
var that = $(this);
that.detach().append('#'+that.data('source'));
```